# upload an Excel file(xls) and save the data in the database sqlite

Tags: excel, flutter, sqlite, flutter-windows

How to uplaod an Excel file(xls) from desktop and save the data in the database sqlite using flutter windows[image: this is file form xls]

this is my table

```
 CREATE TABLE "products" (
    "product_id"  INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,
    "product_name" TEXT NOT NULL  ,
    "product_price" REAL NOT NULL,
    "price_cost" REAL NOT NULL,
    "product_quantity" INTEGER,
   
    
  );
```

uplaod an Excel file(xls) and save the data in the database sqlite

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code generation service, it's a Q&A site about specific programming questions. You didn't ask a question

Comment: And `xls` isn't the real Excel format, it's an obsolete format abandoned since 2007. The actual Excel format is `xlsx`, a ZIP package containing XML files which allows all languages to read it. If you want to avoid compatibility headaches, don't use `xls`. If you google `flutter Excel` you'll find the [Excel package](https://pub.dev/packages/excel) which supports XLSX, not XLS